# Matrix minimal polynomial question

Tags: matrices, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

What is the minimal polynomial of $A$?

$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}
0&0&c\\
1&0&b\\
0&1&a
\end{matrix}\right]$$

I tried to classify each case of eigenvalues and match them with a characteristic polynomial (3 equal, 2 equal and all different), but this became far too complicated.

Is there a simpler way?

(Sorry for my poor english.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The answer to your question is here: [Find the minimal polynomial for the given matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529403/find-the-minimal-polynomial-for-the-given-matrix)